# Please help identify board connector

Tags: connector

I am trying to find a replacement connector for this board which came out of a clarion factory car stereo (Subaru).  I've tried searching various types of connectors but haven't been able to identify it.  There appears to be some very tiny markings on the top: "IRS" and "C2", has anyone seen this before or have an idea of what to search?

[image]

[image]

Comment: CONN, PCB mount, male, blade, x positions, right angle.

Comment: Good place to start is to take some measurements with a caliper. Measure the pitch (blade to blade distance), the blade dimensions, etc.

Comment: I've tried searching that criteria but Google comes up with a very broad set of results.  So far I've tried going directly to Digikey and Mouser and specifying those things but I still haven't found anything close to it.  Is there like a reverse lookup for connectors somewhere?  Seems like there should be.